# How to know which QLineEdit emitted the editingFinished() inside the signal handler?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I want to implement a custom response to user input for several similar `QLineEdit` objects. I want to create a common handler of `editingFinished()` or `textChanged()` signal and assign it to all the `QLineEdit`s. However, the response requires the knowledge of the sender of the signal - for example, it must highlight the entered text with different colors.

How do I know the sender of the signal inside it's handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get pointer to sender with call to [QObject::sender()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender) and then cast this pointer to QLineEdit. Something like

```
void MyClass::onTextChanged(const QString& text)
{
  QLineEdit* edit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(sender());
  if (edit)
  {
    // Do something with QLineEdit
  }
  else
  {
    // Just to make sure that you have not make mistake with connecting signals
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should consider using of QSignalMapper technique: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html

Comment: It support parameter-less signals only. Thus, it cannot be used with `textChanged()`.

Comment: So, you must be more precise in your question. If you want to know the `__value__` of `textChanged(QString __value__)` signal then `QSignalMapper` not an option, but if you want to know only sender and want to identify it uniquely you can use that: `connect(qlineedit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));`