# How to recognise which QObject emitted a SIGNAL in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have many `QLineEdit`'s in my *Main Window*. I have a connected the `editingFinished()` `SIGNAL` of each object to a single `SLOT` in my `QMainWindow` class.
I want to implement my own ***Undo/Redo*** functionality. I find the ***Qt Undo framework*** *pretty difficult to understand & complex to implement*.
So I want to maintain a `QList <QLineEdit *> undoList;` which will store the sequence of `QLineEdit`'s which were modified. I am maintaining an `int` variable to keep track of current state. When Undo/Redo is done I can simply update the `int` variable & find the `QLineEdit` which was edited at that state & then call `undo()` on that `QLineEdit`.
Currently my biggest problem is that since I have connected all my `QLineEdit`'s to a single `SLOT`, I have no information as to which `QLineEdit` emitted that `SIGNAL`.
So I would like to know if there is any way by which I can understand which `QLineEdit` emitted the `SIGNAL`.
Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know which QLineEdit emitted the editingFinished() inside the signal handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025089/how-to-know-which-qlineedit-emitted-the-editingfinished-inside-the-signal-hand)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `sender()` inside the slot to get the the `QObject` that emitted the signal connected to it.

Comment: yup found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025089/how-to-know-which-qlineedit-emitted-the-editingfinished-inside-the-signal-hand?rq=1

Comment: regarding the Qt Undo framework.
Is there any nice web article or some tutorial or something that explains the Qt Undo Framework & how to implement it for beginners like me?
I am struggling to understand from the 2 examples in Qt SDK for 4.8.1. Your help would be most welcome.
Thanks :)

Comment: @CAD_coding I don't know any from memory, but there must be unofficial ones available on the web, you'll have to do some web trawling.